# Calculating floor load strength

Tags: wood, framing, subfloor, joists, load-bearing

Well I'm sure this had been covered over and over. I could not find the formula I seek. I'm building a storage room in the back of a large steel building on my property and I was thinking I'd use the roof of my storage cube as place to put pallets and store junk. Nothing heavy I'd say no more that 300 pounds per pallet so that's about  300 every 4' squared I'm not sure of the span yet I plan to sheath it with osb prob 1/2 but what I'm looking for is a formula I can use something like
 A 2x4 frame spanning 10' with joist spaced at 16' will support =

A 2x4 frame spanning 15' with joist spaced at 16' will support =

A 2x6 frame spanning 10' with joist spaced at 16' will support =

A 2x6 frame spanning 15' with joist spaced at 16' will support =

And so on

Think anyone can help me out?

Comment: You are essentially trying to calculate deflection

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact formulas as I'm sure they're fairly complex but the John Bridge Deflect-o-meter is a good place to start: http://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/deflecto.pl

Comment: That helps a lot. I get the concept amount a single joist will flex under load but what is the L/345. Load divided by that number is the inches the board will flex?